# Cython prange and BLAS slower than sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, cython, openblas

I have an issue when trying to use Cython for accelerating distance (via dot product) calculations. I want compute the distance matrix between each pair of vectors of arrays a and b, where a and b have the same (large) number of dimensions, say 100, a has ~1000-50000 vectors and b has ~100000 vectors. My code remains much slower than the function `euclidean_distances` from sklearn.metrics.pairwise.

I understand that `euclidean_distances` uses BLAS instructions but so am I... I coded two functions that use ddot from BLAS. One is serial and the second uses prange, with the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283906/3563822 to avoid race conditions.

Here is my use case

```
import numpy as np    
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

from pairwise4 import pairwise_sq_fast_serial, pairwise_sq_fast_parallel


n_dim = 100
a = np.random.normal(size=(1000,n_dim))
b = np.random.normal(size=(100000,n_dim))

#reference
%timeit euclidean_distances(a, b, squared=True)
1.32 s ± 12.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#4x slower than scikit-learn...
%timeit np.asarray(pairwise_sq_fast_serial(a,b))
5.73 s ± 51.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#slower than serial!
%timeit np.asarray(pairwise_sq_fast_parallel(a,b)) 
6.77 s ± 291 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The results from the three functions are the same:

```
D1 = euclidean_distances(a, b, squared=True)
D2 = np.asarray(pairwise_sq_fast_serial(a,b))
np.allclose(D1,D2)
True

D3 = np.asarray(pairwise_sq_fast_parallel(a,b))
np.allclose(D1,D3)
True
```

But the problem is that pairwise_sq_fast_parallel is slower than the other two implementations!
My question is: why? am I doing something wrong?

Here's the code of pairwise4.pyx :

```
#cython: boundscheck=False, cdivision=True, wraparound=False, language_level=3, initializedcheck = False

cimport cython
import numpy as np
# from libc.math cimport sqrt
from cython.parallel cimport prange, parallel
cimport openmp

from scipy.linalg.cython_blas cimport ddot

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
def pairwise_sq_fast_serial(const double[:, ::1] X, const double[:, ::1] Y):

    if X.shape[1] != Y.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError("largeurs de X et Y differentes : {} != {}".format(X.shape[1], Y.shape[1]))

    if X.shape[0] > Y.shape[0]:
        print("Warning: Y a moins d'elts que X")

    return pairwise_sq_blas_serial(X, Y)


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
def pairwise_sq_fast_parallel(const double[:, ::1] X, const double[:, ::1] Y):

    if X.shape[1] != Y.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError("largeurs de X et Y differentes : {} != {}".format(X.shape[1], Y.shape[1]))

    if X.shape[0] > Y.shape[0]:
        print("Warning: Y a moins d'elts que X")

    return pairwise_sq_blas_parallel(X, Y)


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
cdef pairwise_sq_blas_serial(const double[:, ::1] X, const double[:, ::1] Y):
    cdef int i, j, k
    cdef int n_dim = X.shape[1]
    cdef double[::1] XminusY = np.empty(n_dim, dtype = np.float64)
    cdef double[:, ::1] result = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]), dtype = np.float64)
    cdef int inc = 1

    for j in range(Y.shape[0]):
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):

            for k in range(n_dim):
                XminusY[k] = X[i,k] - Y[j,k]

            result[i,j] = ddot(&n_dim, &XminusY[0], &inc, &XminusY[0], &inc)

    return result

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
cdef pairwise_sq_blas_parallel(const double[:, ::1] X, const double[:, ::1] Y):
    cdef int num_threads = 4
    cdef int i, j, k, tid
    cdef int n_dim = X.shape[1]
    cdef double[::1] XminusY = np.empty(n_dim * num_threads, dtype = np.float64)
    cdef double[:, ::1] result = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]), dtype = np.float64)
    cdef int inc = 1

    #print('parallel computation !!!!')

    with nogil, parallel(num_threads=num_threads):
        tid = openmp.omp_get_thread_num()
        for j in prange(Y.shape[0], schedule='static', chunksize=2000):
            for i in range(X.shape[0]):
                for k in range(n_dim):
                    XminusY[tid*n_dim + k] = X[i,k] - Y[j,k]

                result[i,j] = ddot(&n_dim, &XminusY[tid*n_dim], &inc, &XminusY[tid*n_dim], &inc)

    return result
```

I'm on a 2016 MacBookPro. I compile pairwise4.pyx with

```
python setup_parallel2.py build_ext --inplace
```

My setup script `setup_parallel2.py` is (adapted from https://github.com/ethen8181/machine-learning/blob/87c0cc130732838b0936a35249f7ee5073e74f00/python/cython/cython.ipynb and https://github.com/ethen8181/machine-learning/blob/87c0cc130732838b0936a35249f7ee5073e74f00/python/cython/setup_parallel.py)

```
# usually the name should only be setup.py
# on the terminal run
# python setup_parallel.py install
import os
import sys
import glob
import numpy as np
from setuptools import Extension, setup
try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
    use_cython = True
except ImportError:
    use_cython = False

# top-level information
NAME = 'pairwise4'
VERSION = '0.0.1'
USE_OPENMP = True


def set_gcc(use_openmp):
    """
    Try to find and use GCC on OSX for OpenMP support

    References
    ----------
    https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/blob/master/setup.py
    """
    # For macports and homebrew
    patterns = ['/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-[0-9].[0-9]',
                '/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-[0-9]',
                '/usr/local/bin/gcc-[0-9].[0-9]',
                '/usr/local/bin/gcc-[0-9]']

    if 'darwin' in sys.platform.lower():
        gcc_binaries = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            gcc_binaries += glob.glob(pattern)

        gcc_binaries.sort()

        if gcc_binaries:
            _, gcc = os.path.split(gcc_binaries[-1])
            os.environ['CC'] = gcc

        else:
            use_openmp = False

    return use_openmp


def define_extensions(use_cython, use_openmp):
    """
    boilerplate to compile the extension the only thing that we need to
    worry about is the modules part, where we define the extension that
    needs to be compiled
    """
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        # compile args from
        # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx
        link_args = []
        compile_args = ['/O2', '/openmp']
    else:
        link_args = []
        compile_args = ['-Wno-unused-function', '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized', '-O3', '-ffast-math']
        if use_openmp:
            compile_args.append('-fopenmp')
            link_args.append('-fopenmp')

        if 'anaconda' not in sys.version.lower():
            compile_args.append('-march=native')

    # recommended approach is that the user can choose not to
    # compile the code using cython, they can instead just use
    # the .c file that's also distributed
    # http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules
    src_ext = '.pyx' if use_cython else '.c'
    names = ['pairwise4']
    modules = [Extension(name,
                         [os.path.join(name + src_ext)],
                         extra_compile_args = compile_args,
                         extra_link_args = link_args) for name in names]

    if use_cython:
        return cythonize(modules)
    else:
        return modules


USE_OPENMP = set_gcc(USE_OPENMP)
setup(
    name = NAME,
    version = VERSION,
    description = 'pairwise distance quickstart',
    ext_modules = define_extensions(use_cython, USE_OPENMP),
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()]
)
```

Comment: As an alternative consider [this](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist)  package.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko : thanks! I'll try this module. FYI, there is also the https://github.com/src-d/kmcuda module which I haven't tried yet.